# How can accept only number in input box

Tags: jquery

i have input box. i want to take only number in it even if user right click text and use mouse to paste.

I do not want plugin..just jquery code

i use keyup event but it no work

if user enter any other character except digit, it should instantly replace with empty string

Answer (score 3):

What I should do is to check the input field when they are leaving the input field

so a jquery blur will do the job. or maybe a change event.

Comment: For simplicity, this is the best option. If you want full control, you'd instead prevent default action on keydown/keypress for any undesired key combinations (which becomes fairly complex to do right and keep expected behavior...), and the ability to preserve the caret placement whenever filtering non-numeric characters for other events (like paste).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you don't want a plugin, there are some very nice ones like [this one](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). You can always add their code into your page instead of having a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a point use.

```
function numonly(root){
    var reet = root.value;   
    var arr1 = reet.length;   
    var ruut = reet.charAt(arr1-1);   
        if (reet.length > 0){   
        var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
                if (!ruut.match(regex)){   
            var reet = reet.slice(0, -1);   
            $(root).val(reet);   
            }   
        }   
    }
    //Then use the event handler onkeyup='numonly(this)'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test"  value="0" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#test").keyup(function(){
        $(this).val( parseInt($(this).val()) );
    });
});
```

this will make your input to always contain numeric input

Comment: this not work when user right click textbox and paste nondigit

Comment: yes i try..your code not work..try this step..when page load, use mouse to right click on input and paste nondigit..it accepts

Comment: This will also create havoc for caret placement.

Comment: trigger your listener in the end, this will prevent inserting on page load, like this:
$("#test").keyup(function(){
        $(this).val( parseInt($(this).val()) );
    }).keyup();